# React-Redux Provider Inference w/ Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have been teaching myself some typescript and came across an issue I don't fully understand. I have been able to develop a workaround, but it appears to weaken type-safety.

A minimal code example of the problem is as follows:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Action, createStore, Reducer, Store } from "redux";

interface IState {
    turns: string[];
}

type TAction1 = "ACTION_1";

interface IAction1 extends Action<TAction1> {
    payload: string;
}

type TAppAction = IAction1; // Assume other action interfaes will be added via union.

// The reducer here doesn't do anything.
const reducer: Reducer<IState, TAppAction> = (state = { turns: [] }) => state;

// The Store type shown is the type returned by createStore.
// A workaround that works is to convert type to Store<IState> which appears to implicitly weaken the type of store.
const store: Store<IState, TAppAction> = createStore(reducer);

// A workaround is to use TSX here.
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Provider, { store }, // Error here
        React.createElement("div")),
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The error returned from Typescript is as follows:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ store: Store<IState, IAction1>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes & ProviderProps<Action<any>>'.
      Type '{ store: Store<IState, IAction1>; }' is not assignable to type 'ProviderProps<Action<any>>'.
        Types of property 'store' are incompatible.
          Type 'Store<IState, IAction1>' is not assignable to type 'Store<any, Action<any>>'.
            Types of property 'dispatch' are incompatible.
              Type 'Dispatch<IAction1>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<Action<any>>'.
                Type 'Action<any>' is not assignable to type 'IAction1'.ts(2769)
index copy.ts(13, 5): 'payload' is declared here.
```

Clearly no overload is found and the last two lines I find confusing and lead me to ask:

1. Why `Action<any>` is inferred for `Provider` and subsequently `ProviderProps`? Have I misunderstood what is happening here? In the second last line the types are suddenly appearing in reversed order?
2. As `Provider` is a generic type, I expected that I might instead specify `Provider<TAppAction>` explicitly, however the expression could not be parsed. Is this an incorrect use of `React.createElement`?

I am using the following:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "css-modules-typescript-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.1",
    "ts-loader": "^6.1.2",
    "tslint": "^5.20.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cdn-plugin": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  }
```

Finally, I classify myself as somewhat of a newbie to TS. Any comments, feedback, or pointers are appreciated.

My references are:

1. [The Redux Basic Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/basics/example)
2. [The Redux Usage with Typescript Recipe](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript)
3. [The React-Redux Basic Tutorial](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial)

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles without error:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Action, createStore, Reducer, Store } from "redux";

interface IState {
    turns: string[];
}

type TAction1 = "ACTION_1";

interface IAction1 extends Action<TAction1> {
    payload: string;
}

type TAppAction = IAction1; // Assume other action interfaes will be added via union.

// The reducer here doesn't do anything.
const reducer: Reducer<IState, TAppAction> = (state = { turns: [] }) => state;

// The Store type shown is the type returned by createStore.
// A workaround that works is to convert type to Store<IState> which appears to implicitly weaken the type of store.
const store: Store<IState, TAppAction> = createStore(reducer);

const MyApp = () =>  ( <> </>);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
      <MyApp />
    </Provider>,
   document.getElementById("react-root")

);
```

P.S.

> Why Action`<any>` is inferred

TSC is likely saying that the type mismatch which triggered the error would still have happened regardless of that type `T` was used to define the type `Action<T>`.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the equivalent TS for the TSX above?

Comment: The question "Can I have .ts instead of .tsx ?" is the same as question "Can I have React (and its `ReactDOM.render` without JSX ?". Because the only difference between .ts and .tsx is that the latter triggers additional JSX-related processing. And the answer is: Yes, you can. See this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html).